# Magento 2 multiple stores problem using parked domains from old magento 1.9 site

Tags: magento2, stores, multiple

Being unsuccessful in migrating a 1.9 multiple store site to Magento 2 i have set up a new install and manually imported and set up all the cats products etc etc.

The issue i have is that in magento 1.9 i have multiple stores using parked domains and i found very good help pages to guide me thro the process.

How ever in Magento 2 i can not find any help to set up my situation of parked domains

I could change from parked domain but as my old site is current do not what to change the parked domains and bring the old site down yet.

The issue lies in what the settings should be in index.php and .htaccess files

Any help or direction would be appreciated

index file from 1.9

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'xxxx.com.au':
    case 'www.xxxx.com.au':
        $mageRunCode = 'xxxx';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

xxxx being domain name